# LINQ to Entites/IQueryable: Sorting on multiple fields

Tags: linq, sorting, iqueryable

I have the following that I'd like to sort:

```
IQueryable<Map> list;
list = from item in ctx.MAP
         .Include("C")
         .Include("L")
         .Include("L.DP")
       select item;
return list.OrderBy(m=>(m.L.DP.Name + m.L.Code));
```

This works, but it sorts alphabetically - so 12 comes before 9.  (Assume Code is a numeric field)

What is the best way to sort this so Code is sorted numerically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to use the ThenBy extension method to be able to sort by multiple fields ;)
In your case that would be

```
 return list.OrderBy(m=>m.L.DP.Name).ThenBy(m => m.L.Code);
```

Comment: Any way to do this if m.L.Code is actually a string, and needs to be converted to an int?

Comment: probably int.Parse would work, you can convert it directly in the lambda expression and it is then sorted numerically

Answer (score 0):

```
 var results = db.Blogs.AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(sr => new
                    {
                        Searchresult = sr,
                        Words = Regex.Split(sr.Name, @"[^\S\r\n {1,}").Union(Regex.Split(sr.Name2, @"[^\S\r\n]{1,}"))
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Words.Count(w => {
                        foreach (var item in searchTerms)
                        {
                            if(w.ToLower().Contains(item))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                           return false;
                    }))
                    .Select(x => x.Searchresult);
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain this code so someone coming along can understand it and why it might be an answer to this question?